# self.location.href with validation

Tags: javascript

I really could do with some help with a form redirection and validation issue for my website.

I’ve been successful in getting the input “password” to redirect to the input value, however if users get the password wrong they get a 404 error - which is correct, but not great for the user.

My question is, is there anyway of having the form validated against a txt or xml file on the server with a list of passwords to validate against before submit??  So the user gets an alert if incorrect rather than 404!

Below is a sample of what currently works, your help is appreciated!!

```
<html><head>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">

function login() {
   if (validLogin()) {
      password = document.userInfos.password.value;
      self.location.href=
        ""+password+"";
      }
   }
function validLogin() {
   if (isBlank(document.userInfos.password.value)){
      alert("Can't be blank");
      document.userInfos.password.focus();
      return false;
      }
   return true;      
   }
function isBlank(s) {
   return (s == "");
   }

   function doKey(e) {
//check to see if the return key was pressed ...
if( event.keyCode == 13){ 
//call the login function ...
login();
//prevent the page from reloading ...
return false;
}
}

//listen for keypress events and then call doKey()
document.onkeypress = doKey;

</SCRIPT>

</head>

        <form  NAME="userInfos" >


<INPUT TYPE="password" NAME="password" LENGTH="20" style="color: #333333" size="23" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<INPUT TYPE="button" style="color: #333333" onClick="login()" VALUE=" View ">
</form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Do not check passwords in client-side JavaScript**; any visitor would be able to obtain a usable password using "View Source". If possible, instead check passwords on the server using a PHP script, CGI script, or an htpasswd file.

**If you are using a free web host** that does not allow any better option, you could make an AJAX request for your URL and check the status code:

```
var prefix = "/~myusername/passwords/", suffix = ".html";
var url = prefix + document.userInfos.password.value + suffix;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // need some more code to support IE 6
xhr.open('GET', url);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xhr.readyState !== 4) {
        return;
    }

    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        // It's possible to grab user-specific settings from xhr.responseText,
        // (e.g. the URL to redirect to), but for simplicity's sake...
        location.href = url;
    } else {
        alert('Password incorrect');
    }

};

xhr.send();
```

However, keep in mind the following **limitations**:

- The protected HTML files should be in a **separate directory** from the login page and password files.
- The name of that directory **must be hard to predict**.
- To **revoke a user's access**, you need to **rename the directory** containing the protected HTML files and update the files for all other users' passwords accordingly.
- Directly linking to protected files exposes them (until the directory is renamed), and **protected files may show up on Google** or other search engines for a variety of known and unknown reasons.
- There is no protection against **brute-force password guessing** and **exposure of passwords through log files**.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am still stuck on how this works, currently the user types in a code / password to access a html page, the code is the name of the html page and I may have several pages used in this way, in a way - its a poor mans password protected site.   according to Google analytics - lots of people are getting the code wrong and being shown a 404 page.

The above sample code sorts out the redirection from the form, i just need that part validating against some other file before the user gets 404, or how to implement your current suggestion.

Many thanks again